# Error al ordenar un objeto por una propiedad

Tags: javascript, objeto, ordenamiento

Tengo la funcion que devuelve un array:

```
 function loadData() {
    const auto1 = new Automovil("Peugeot", "206", 200000.0, 4);
    const moto1 = new Motocicleta("Honda", "Titan", 60000.0, "125cc");
    const auto2 = new Automovil("Peugeot", "208", 250000.0, 5);
    const moto2 = new Motocicleta("Yamaha", "YBR", 80500.5, "160cc");
    const data = [auto1, moto1, auto2, moto2];
    return data;
  }
```

y quisiera obtener un resultado de la siguiente manera:

```
Peugeot 208
Peugeot 206 
Yamaha YBR
Honda Titan
```

> Como verán, el resultado es ordenar por precio (de mayor a menor) y obtener marca y modelo. No se como hacerlo. Lo que hice es esto:

```
function ordenar(data) {
    const ordenado = [];
    data.map((item, index) => {
      ordenado.push(item.precio);
    });

    console.log("no ordenado: " + ordenado);
    console.log(
      "ordenado: " +
        ordenado.sort((a, b) => {
          return a - b;
        })
    );
  }
```

Esta funcion me devuelve un array correctamente ordenado, pero unicamente de precios. No me alcanza para lo que busco. En el momento que se carga el array ordenado:

```
data.map((item, index) => {
      ordenado.push(item.precio);
    });
```

intento crear un array de objetos algo asi:

```
data.map((item, index) => {
      ordenado.push({
        precio: item.precio,
        marca: item.marca,
        modelo: item.modelo
      });
    });
```

Pero la salida es `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Me podrian indicar un poco como seguir para solucionarlo? Muchas gracias

Comment: Por qué no simplemente ordenarlos directamente en lugar de copiar sólo el precio a un nuevo array? Puedes ordenarlo haciendo a.precio - b.precio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uno de los problemas que veo es la parte donde realizas la impresión, ya que estás imprimendo el array completamente, lo que hace que se vean los:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Y por otro lado necesitas realizar comparación de los objetos dentro del array para poder realizar un ordenamiento de estos.

Te dejo mi script para que evalúes los resultados. Espero que te sea de utilidad:

```
class Automovil {
 constructor(marca, modelo, precio, cilindrada){
    this.marca= marca;
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
 }   
}

class Motocicleta {
 constructor(marca, modelo, precio, cilindrada){
    this.marca= marca;
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
 }   
}

// Función de construcción de los datos  
function loadData() {
  return [
     new Automovil("Peugeot", "206", 200000.0, 4),
     new Motocicleta("Honda", "Titan", 60000.0, "125cc"),
     new Automovil("Peugeot", "208", 250000.0, 5),
     new Motocicleta("Yamaha", "YBR", 80500.5, "160cc"),
  ];
}

// Función de compración

// Se pasará como parámetro a la función "sort" del array. Para este caso voy a asumir que en todas las clases de vehículos que utilizas,
// el precio va directamente en el atributo "precio", por lo que este será el que utilizaré para ordenar mis elementos.


function comparator(vehiculoA, vehiculoB){
  // cuando el precio del vehículo b es menor que el precio del vehículo a
  if ( vehiculoB.precio < vehiculoA.precio ){
    return -1;
  }
  // cuando el precio del vehículo b es mayor que el precio del vehículo a
  if ( vehiculoB.precio > vehiculoA.precio ){
     return 1;
  }
  // el precio fué igual
  return 0;
}

// Y mi hilo de ejecución será:

const data = loadData();
const ordenado = data.sort(comparator);
// en este punto los datos deberían estar ordenados, por lo que 
// lo único que nos queda es mostrarlos, esto puede hacerse de 
// muchas maneras en este caso voy solo a ciclar sobre el array
// e imprimo de acuerdo a tu salida esperada
ordenado.forEach(({ marca, modelo }) => console.log(marca, modelo));
```

Si por ejemplo quieres invertir el ordenamiento, inviertes en la función comparator el vehículo a por el vehículo b.